# Cross server File Upload in IE 8/9 for ASP.Net WebAPI

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, upload, asp.net-web-api

I have read tons about File Upload for IE 8/9. However, I have not been able to successfully create any solution for my case. I am pretty new to programming for the web so this could stem from my lack of knowledge about protocols and such.

On the server side I have ASP.NET WebApi: an API that is meant to handle file uploads, which works fine when using Fiddler and direct calls to that server.

On the client I use HTML (not HTML 5), and KnockoutJS.

Because of the architecture in place, there are 2 servers: one for serving clients and other misc. activities (lets call it A), and another which hosts the file upload API and manages large volumes of data (server B).

I have a page on the client (coming from A) which uploads files to the 2nd server (server B).

I came across jquery.form.js and read that it supports IE uploads as well. So I tried implementing the code from a [tutorial from some site](http://www.rgvwebshop.com/2013/01/file-upload-with-knockoutjs-and-jquery). Unfortunately it does not work and the browser shows the following error:

```
OPTIONS http://B/Files/Post/3/g/ 404 (Not found) jquery.js:8724
send jquery.js:8724               jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:8154
fileUploadXhr                                    jquery.form.js:321
$.fn.ajaxSubmit                                  jquery.form.js:239
(anonymous function)                              knockout.bindings.js:17
jQuery.event.dispatch                            jquery.js:5116
elemData.handle                                  jquery.js:4787
OPTIONS http://B/Files/Post/3/g/ Origin http://A is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.                         jquery.js:8724
send jquery.js:8724                              jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:8154
fileUploadXhr                                    jquery.form.js:321
$.fn.ajaxSubmit                                  jquery.form.js:239
(anonymous function)                           knockout.bindings.js:17
jQuery.event.dispatch                            jquery.js:5116
elemData.handle                                  jquery.js:4787
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://B/Files/Post/3/g/. Origin http://A is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. test.html:1
```

On the servers I have implemented everything from [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api), which talks about CORS for WebApi's.

Can anyone help? I am looking out for code snippets in HTML and javascript/jquery that does the trick for both IE 8/9 and other modern browsers.

Comment: If you are simply looking for an upload library that reliably handles cross origin environments in all possible browsers, including IE 8 and 9, may I suggest [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com).  I'm actually a maintainer for this library.  Take a look, it may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for that Ray, but I'm looking at something that does not require me to dole out the moolah ! :)

Comment: Your needs are quite complex.  Cross-origin uploading w/ associated features in IE8 & 9 is not a simple task.  You usually get what you pay for.  Good luck.